# Как выделить цветом произвольные столбики в диаграмме в библиотеке matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Подскажите пожалуйста как выделить отдельным цветом столбцы с определенными индексами.
У меня следующий код, в котором в качестве индексов использованы названия субъектов страны и мне необходимо визуально выделить некоторые из них.

```
stats_2017_1th_year_mort_2017_df = dataset_stats_2017_df['1th_year_mort_2017']
stats_2017_1th_year_mort_2017_df.index = dataset_stats_2017_df['Subyekt']

stats_2017_1th_year_mort_2017_df = stats_2017_1th_year_mort_2017_df.sort_values()
rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 19, 19
stats_2017_1th_year_mort_2017_df.plot(kind="barh")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример. Поскольку вы не предоставили воспроизводимый пример данных, могу только на искусственных данных показать. Просто берёте `ax.patches` и красите нужные патчи через `set_color`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [10, 20, 42, 15]
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data})
ax = df.plot(kind='barh')
ax.patches[2].set_color('r')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, заработало!)